# How to run a function in the background while running other ones in the front?

Tags: python

I'm sort of new to python, and I'm trying to build a voice-controlled home automation system. Everything's going out really well, except for one thing.
I need the system to stop whatever it's doing when I say 'stop.' for example, when it's playing music, or when it's telling me the news, if I say "stop", it stop everything and go back to standby mode.

How can I make it so that there's  a python process in the background always listening for a "stop" while doing other stuff in the front?

this is my code for the particular part:

```
def stop():
    #code_that_listens_for_"stop"

def main():
    #code_that_listens_and_executes_commands

# runs at the start of the program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = main).start()
    Thread(target = stop).start()
```

is my code correct?

Thanks! This is my first question at stackexchange, any help would be greatly appreciated ^^

Answer (score 0):

Instead Of Thread use Process you will get more advantages like no gil, fast, efficient

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def stop():
    #code_that_listens_for_"stop"

def main():
    #code_that_listens_and_executes_commands

# runs at the start of the program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=stop).start()
    Process(target=main).start()
```

Comment: I fixed "from threading import Thread" to "from threading import Process" but my text editor(Atom) says that I can't import name Process.

Comment: ans updated my friend, `from multiprocessing import Process`